# MongoDB: Slow query

Tags: mongodb

I am running a mongo query like this

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({stringField:"stringValue", arrayField:{$exists:true, $ne:[]}}).sort({dateField:-1})
```

The collection has approx. 10^6 documents. I have indexes on the stringField and dateField (both ascending). This query takes **~3-4 seconds** to run.

However, if I change my query to **either of the below**, it executes **within 100ms**

Remove `$ne`

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({stringField:"stringValue", arrayField:{$exists:true}}).sort({dateField:-1})
```

Remove `$exists`

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({stringField:"stringValue", arrayField:{$ne:[]}}).sort({dateField:-1})
```

Remove sort

```
db.getCollection('collection').find({stringField:"stringValue", arrayField:{$exists:true, $ne:[]}})
```

Use `arrayField.0`

```
db.getCollection('foodfulfilments').find({stringField:"stringValue", "arrayField.0":{$exists:true}}).sort({dateField:-1})
```

The explain of these queries do not provide any insights to why the first query is so slow?

MongoDb version 3.4.18

Comment: After you execute all other queries, if you execute the original query again, does it still take 3-4 seconds?

Comment: Yes. Tried multiple times. Same results.